# How to force preprocessor to use desired data type in C/C++?

Tags: c, if-statement, c-preprocessor, primitive-types

I would like to test bit size of unsigned long using macro. One would think that if you specify `0UL` it will evaluate as unsigned long, but according this short example it is not true. I compiled it using MinGW on 32bit architecture, so `~0UL` should get me `0xFFFFFFFF`:

```cpp
#if (((~0UL) >> 31) >> 1) // expected 0, double shift to get around mod 32 limit
   #define UL_BIT_SIZE 64
#else
   #define UL_BIT_SIZE 32
#endif

printf("%d, %X\n", UL_BIT_SIZE, ((~0UL) >> 31) >> 1);
```

Output:    `64, 0`

Funny thing is that if I change `UL` to `L` or simply skip the postfix it's working as expected. Can anyone please explain what's the problem here, what's the cause and how can it be solved?

Comment: Is this even necessary? `#define UL_BIT_SIZE  (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned long))`

Comment: Can u be 100% sure that `CHAR_BIT` is always defined and/or it is not statically set to 8 ?

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>` and is not necessarily always 8.

Comment: U didn't get my point it seems, i'll be more specific. If i have some atypical architecture with lets say char of size 18b, how will u ensure that `CHAR_BIT` will be set to 18? Is it somehow generated (i doubt it), or u have to set it manualy/download header `limits.h` for that specific architecture ? If it's the other case what makes u so sure that there exist version of `limits.h` for any existing architecture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C preprocessor does not know types or C keywords.

Preprocessor arithmetic is done with the largest integer type from `stdint.h` which is `intmax_t` or  `uintmax_t` depending on the sign of the operands.

Comment: Thank u for quick reply. I found this section in c99 standard, but why is this piece of code working (outputing `32, 0`) for `0L` or `0` ? Shouldn't be the result `64, 0` no matter what type preprocessor chose? If u take maximum representable number that fits into `intmax_t`, in my case `-1` or `~0` and shift it 32 bits right u are supposed to get non-zero number no matter what.